# Automatically sizing a Windows.Forms form to match its cefsharp content

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

How can I get JavaScript in cefsharp's `ChromiumWebBrowser` to run before the host `Windows.Form` form is visible?

I want this so that I can resize the form to match the content it will be showing, without the size flickering.

Currently I set the form's width and then in JavaScript I look at `document.body.scrollHeight`, and use this in C# to set the dialog's client height to match. However this resizing is visible, which is ugly.

Comment: Try calling `browser.CreateControl()`

Comment: Thanks @amaitland, I have tried that and it doesn't help.  Nothing actually happens until the form is visible.  (I have the JavaScript code call me back via an XMLHttpRequest, and I don't see anything until then.  I tested it by calling CreateControl() and then calling DoEvents() in a loop for a few seconds.)

Comment: By default `CefSharp` runs using `settings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true`, so the message handling is done in a separate thread, so `Application.DoEvents()` probably isn't going to do a whole lot. Calling `CreateControl()` is enough to get `LoadingStateChanged` to fire for me. If you haven't already dig through the source.